# Segmentation fault when accessing specific pointer

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, malloc

I'm trying to code my own malloc and free in C for a project. For the most part, it's going fine but I can't wrap my head around a strange Segmentation Fault it's giving me. I reproduced the code that was giving the error in a simplified form:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MEMORY_SIZE 4096
static char memory[MEMORY_SIZE];

typedef struct metaData{
    unsigned short isFree; //1 if free, 0 if allocated
    unsigned short size;
} metaData;

int main(){
    metaData *head = (metaData *) memory;
    printf("%d\n", (head+2031)->size);
    printf("%d\n", (head+2032)->size);
    puts("Segmentation up here???");

    return 0;
}
```

`memory` is a static array of chars of size 4096. The first `printf` prints out a 0. But the next `printf` is a segfault. I am able to manipulate the `metaData` struct at every pointer up until `head+2032`. Does anyone have any idea why?

Comment: It's pointless calling `malloc()` without storing the pointer it returns.

Comment: It isn't the malloc from C. Although technically still pointless it's useful for error checking to just call it. I will make a runnable code snippet.

Comment: If the memory block is size 4096 bytes, then to validly index the 2033rd `struct` would mean the `struct` size is only 2 bytes. If it were 3 bytes, then 2033 records would need 6099 bytes. It looks as though you could have broken the memory bounds.

Comment: Interesting. Well, the struct is 4 bytes. Although not every element in the array is treated as a struct. I do account for this in the actual program yet the same problem persists. I have more code to show that could give more detail if you wanna look.

Comment: If `sizeof(metaData)` is packed, and 4 bytes, then to access the 2033rd would need over 8000 bytes allocated, but you only have 4096. Adding `2033` to the pointer adds `sizeof(metdata) * 2033` to the base address.

Comment: Yeah but see that's why it is so confusing. Why does printing the element at head+2031 print 0 and not give a segmentation fault

Comment: So? Faults are not guaranteed to happen. Run the first red light - nothing. Next red light - kaboom! Third red light - win the lottery.

Comment: Doing illegal things in C is not guaranteed to crash your program. It can silently corrupt memory or do other unexpected things with no clear symptoms. Don't take the absence of a crash as a sign that your code is correct. Accessing anything past `head+1023` is illegal.

Comment: Alright well, I'm unclear on why specifically it's breaking the memory-bound where it is but I get it enough. it is definitely something to do with the metaData struct being too big. I thought my malloc accounted for this but i guess its treating everything as metadata and not as chars with occasional metadata. I keep playing with it, Thank you

Comment: It's *undefined behaviour* to access beyond the bounds of allocated memory. So there is no point trying to reasom the why and wherefore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pointer arithmetic in C is performed in base units of the **size of the pointed-to type**. Your `head` is a pointer to a `metaData` structure, which has a size of `2 × sizeof(unsigned short)`. Assuming (as is likely, but not certain) that an `unsigned short` has a size of 2 bytes on your platform, then that "base unit" will be 4 bytes.

Thus, when the `head + 2031` calculation is made, the value of `4 × 2031` (which is 8124) will be added to the address in `head` to give the result of that expression. So, with the following `->size` operator, you are attempting to reference memory that is 8,126 bytes<sup>1</sup> from the location of the beginning of your `memory` array – but that array is declared as only **4096 bytes** (`sizeof(char)` is, by definition, 1 byte).

Accessing memory beyond the declared size of an array is undefined behaviour (UB); once you have invoked such UB (as you do in *both* `printf` calls), many different things can happen, and in unpredictable ways. A "segmentation fault" (trying to read or write memory to which your program does not have access) is one possible manifestation of UB. (Another possible manifestation is that no error is reported and the program *appears* to work properly; in many people's opinion, that's the worst kind!)

---

<sup>1</sup> 8,124 bytes will be the offset of the start of the potentially pointed-to `meteData` structure; because `size` is preceded by another `unsigned short` member, then another two bytes will be added.